# Remove 'play' symbol from video thumbnail generated by Google Photos API

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-photos, google-photos-api

Using the Google Photos API I would like to display the thumbnails associated with videos **without** the play icon overlaying the image.

This is what it looks like. How can I remove the white play arrow?

[image]

I know from the documentation that "to access the thumbnail of the video use any of the image base url parameters.":
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items

To get a list of files, I use the Google Javascript API `gapi`

```
gapi.client.request({
    'path': 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': { "filters": { "mediaTypeFilter": { "mediaTypes": ["VIDEO"] }  } }
    }).then(displayTheResults);
```

This gives me results like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "mediaItems": [
            {
                "id": "iiiiiiiiiiiiii",
                "productUrl": "https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/iiiiiiiiiiii",
                "baseUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "mimeType": "video/mp4",
                "mediaMetadata": {
                    "creationTime": "2021-02-24T11:23:26Z",
                    "width": "1920",
                    "height": "1080",
                    "video": {
                        "fps": 29.609994326070606,
                        "status": "READY"
                    }
                },
                "filename": "VID_1111111111.mp4"
            }
            ....
        ]
    },
    "body": { .... },
    "headers": { ... },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": null
}
```

To generate the thumbnail my base-url becomes:

```
var videoThumbnail = baseUrl + "=w300-h200-c";
```

Is it possible to remove the big 'play' icon from the thumbnail?